# Algorithm for bilevel optimisation ==> implementation in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to implement a bilevel model to pyomo. Specifically, when I get the results from the upper level, I want the lower level model to inherit values from the solution of the variables of the upper level. And I want to implement a for loop between the models, in order to iterate until their objective functions converge.

Both the upper and lower level models are MILP and will be solved with CPLEX.

My question is how can the lower level model inherit the values of the upper level as parameters. This is my implementation but it is not correct. How can I formulate this?

Upper level model

---

```
up = AbstractModel()
up.c = Set() 
up.h = Set() 
up.p = Set() 
up.t = RangeSet(50) 
up.INH = Var(up.p, up.h, up.t, within=NonNegativeIntegers)
```

---

Lower level model

```
lp = AbstractModel()
lp.c = Set() 
lp.h = Set() 
lp.p = Set() 
lp.t = RangeSet(50) 
lp.INH2 = Param(lp.p, lp.h, lp.t, default=instance.INH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pyomo used to have a Bilevel framework to model bilevel problems, but since `pyomo 6.0.1` it was moved to [PAO](https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

In the PAO environtment you can create a full block which will have the upper level and the lower level optimization problem. Upper level is modeled as usual, while the Lower level use the `pao.SubModel()` class. That SubModel class still needs to be inside the upper level model, and you need to fix the upper level variables using the argument `fix= x` into the `SubModel` PAO class

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
from pao.pyomo import *
#Create a model object
M = pe.ConcreteModel()
#Define decision variables
M.x = pe.Var(bounds=(0,None))
M.y = pe.Var(bounds=(0,None))
#using submodel to modeling lower lovel problem
#Fixing x and not fixing y indicate that x is a upper-var and y is a lower-var
M.L = SubModel(fixed=M.x)
...
with Solver('pao.pyomo.FA') as solver:
    results = solver.solve(M)
```

Now you can add objectives and constraints in upper and lower level using `M` and `M.L`, respectively.